# How to search products in arremate.com.br,submarino.com.br,mercadolivre.com.br,parceiro.buscape.com.br using UPC, EAN ,gs1_128 codes in java?

Tags: java, e-commerce, barcode

How to search products in major Brazilian e-commerce sites using UPC, EAN Gs1_128, ITF codes in java (can be a rest or soap api or even GET request to give me the exact product page )?
some of the giant sites in Brazil are:  http://www.arremate.com.br/ , http://www.submarino.com.br/,http://www.mercadolivre.com.br/, http://parceiro.buscape.com.br, etc

Please give you inputs. Thanks.